# Unable to access System.Windows.Forms for Android app

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

We built .net application in C# which uses System.Windows.Forms.Datavisualization.Charting.

I tried Xamarin android sample application successfully but unable to use System.Windows.Forms.

How can we port above application to android platform?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in the [documentation](http://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/System.Windows.Forms/) `System.Windows.Forms.Datavisualization.Charting` isn't one of the ported namespaces in the framework. You can't use it.

You have to revert to another charting framework.